# A module can not access JpaRepository interface that is in the other module

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I am using IntelliJ and Gradle for a sample project. There are two modules.

1. demo-core module
   It has entity and repository classes. build.gradle file is like the below.

```
apply plugin: 'java'

group 'com.example'
version '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.200'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.5.3'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.0'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I added CustomerRepository class for Customer entity in demo-core module.

```
package example.springboot.entity;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {
}
```

2. demo-web module

This is a web module and uses the repository interface like the below.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoWebApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoWebApp.class, args);
    }
    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner demo(CustomerRepository repository) {
        return (args) -> {
            // save a few customers
            repository.save(new Customer("Jack", "Bauer"));
            repository.save(new Customer("Chloe", "O'Brian"));
            repository.save(new Customer("Kim", "Bauer"));
            repository.save(new Customer("David", "Palmer"));
            repository.save(new Customer("Michelle", "Dessler"));
        };
    }
}
```

This is build.gradle file for demo-web module.

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group 'com.example'
version '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':demo-core')
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.0'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

but I can't use JpaRepsitory methods with this error.

```
/Users/dgkim/Downloads/demo/demo-web/src/main/java/example/springboot/DemoWebApp.java:19: error: cannot access JpaRepository
            repository.save(new Customer("Jack", "Bauer"));
                      ^
  class file for org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository not found
```

So, I created a new interface wrapping the CustomerRepository in demo-core module like this.

```
@Service
public class CustomerFinder {
    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    public Optional<Customer> findCustomer(Long id)   {
        return customerRepository.findById(id);
    }
}
```

My Controller class uses the wrapper interface like the below.

```
@RestController
public class CustomerController {
    @Autowired
    private CustomerFinder finder;

    @GetMapping("/customer/{id}")
    public String customer(@PathVariable Long id)  {
        Optional<Customer> customerOptional = finder.findCustomer(id);
        if(customerOptional.isPresent()) return "find customer. " + customerOptional.get().getLastName();
        else return "no entity";
    }
}
```

It works. JpaRepository methods can be accessed in the same module but demo-web module that has a dependency on demo-core can not access it. DemoWebApp class can access CustomerRepository interface itself but can not access the super interface (JpaRepository).

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

try to change core module dependencies from `implementation` to `api`

---

`implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.5.3'`

to

`api 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.5.3'`

---

You can see the difference between `api` and `implementation` [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation)